# Appcelerator:Finding current position of Image

Tags: iphone, imageview, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am finding the current X and Y position in '*touchend*' event. Now say the original position of ImageView is ; **left=100** and **top=100**. On *touchend* it just gives value in 2 digits that is either 8,10 or 9,11 etc. Now I am not sure what's the offset of image view. If it is lastLeft+x and lastTop+y then it's not gonna work at all. What all I want to save current position of Image at TouchEnd in Db so that I could restore it later.

Kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original answer was incorrect: here's an updated version.

The globalpoint property in the event object contains the coordinates on the screen that the user clicked on, while the x and y properties are the coordinates within the view at which the user clicked. By taking one away from the other (and, depending on whether your screen has a status bar, allowing for that too) you can work out the top/left of the object after an animation finishes.

I've put together a demo that works in 1.6.0 which demonstrates this (just create a new project and replace app.js with the following code)

```
// Windows
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    url: 'KS_nav_ui.png',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#f00'
});

image.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {

    var left = e.globalPoint.x - e.x,
        top = e.globalPoint.y - e.y - 20; // The 20 accounts for status bar

    Ti.API.info('Starting left: ' + left);
    Ti.API.info('Starting top: ' + top);

});

image.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {

    var newX = e.x + image.animatedCenter.x - image.width/2;
    var newY = e.y + image.animatedCenter.y - image.height/2;

    image.animate({center:{x:newX,y:newY}, duration:1});

});

image.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {

    var left = e.globalPoint.x - e.x,
        top = e.globalPoint.y - e.y - 20; // The 20 accounts for status bar

    Ti.API.info('Finishing left: ' + left);
    Ti.API.info('Finishing top: ' + top);

});

window.add(image);

window.open();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does give top and left but not the current one. It gives the value which I set initially. Kindly guide

Comment: Ah, OK. You're dragging the image?

Comment: You're probably going to need to use the 'globalPoint' property on the event then, since that gives the coordinates of the event in terms of the screen. It won't map to the top / left exactly but given you know the width / original position of the image you should be able to work it out from there. I'll see if I can put an example together..

Comment: it would be a great help if you can do it. I am using 2 ImageView, one imageview is being dragged on other. BTW, does not globalpoint returns same value like event.x and y?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a demo that I think gives you what you're looking for.

Comment: Thx Craig, I was not being able to use this code due to work load,I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Ok I just tried and it seems not working. Let me tell you what I did. I moved it from origin point; x=21 Y =107 and moved to another point;x=200;y-145. For testing purpose I used the moveend value in ImageView constructor by setting left and top of ImageView but it was not putting on same point.

Comment: ok it seems working, what I was doing that I was ignoring the value after decimal hence was not getting accuracy. I just tried your code and would now try to incorporate it in mine. Thx a Bunch! will let you know.

Comment: Hey! I just checked by dragging one ImageView over other. It's working! Thanks a bunch Bro! thanks a bunch!